# APIDOCJS - Adding line break into Description

Tags: api-doc

I would like to add a line break into the description. But I cannot find the proper syntax for it.

What I want to achieve is all these 3 @apiError will combine under the same component.

```
@apiError [(group)] [{type}] field [description]

@apiError {String} 400 1 or more parameters is empty. 
@apiError {String} 400 Your account is suspended.
@apiError {String} 400 Your account not found.
```

Reference: http://apidocjs.com/#param-api-error

Maybe tricks like this will do, but I am not testing it yet.

```
@apiError {String} 400 1 or more parameters is empty. <br> Your account is suspended. <br> Your account not found.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update.. this syntax works.

```
@apiError {String} 400 1 or more parameters is empty <br> Your account is suspended <br> Your account not found.
```